# How to flash ag-grid cell while updating the data using api.updateRowData()?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to achieve cell/row flashing in ag-grid(angular), depending on whether my grid data has updated or new rows have been added. I am using api.updateRowData() to update/add the rows into the grid. My column definition has enableCellChangeFlash:true for the "model" column. My expectation is that when I add or update the rows the model column cell should flash for that row. The flashing is achievable when I am using rowNode.setDataValue() to change a particular cell value but not with api.updateRowData(). Please help me out.
(All official ag-grid examples I see online for cell flashing are either updating individual cell values or flashing with api.cellFlash() wherein they know which cells to flash. In my case I do not know what column for a row might have changed. I was expecting ag-grid would take care of that)

I cannot share my codebase so I have created a mock one to achieve a similar target.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-install-and-simple-example-angular-7-udcjnd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

In this example, when I am adding a new row to the grid with updateRowData(), I want my "model" column for new row to flash on creation. How do I achieve this?

Comment: will something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-install-and-simple-example-angular-7-pybcun?file=src/app/app.component.ts) help?

Comment: Thanks for your response! In this example of yours i would like only the model column in the newly created row to flash. Actually i want to flash the exact cell for a row update too but I don't want to calculate which cell i am suppose to flash as I am simply trying to updateRowData(). I was hoping that part would be taken care of by ag-grid in someway.

Comment: you can specify which column to flash, see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-install-and-simple-example-angular-7-qjfumx?file=src/app/app.component.ts) Stackblitz.

Comment: in my real project the grid handling the cell update is in a different project managed by another team. I can update the grid only with api.updateRowData() and change my column definition to enableCellFlashChange: true, hence i specifically wanted to know if there is a mechanism to handle this without calculating which cells changed because otherwise I will need to get column data for current row vs previous row and then check which column changed to flash it with flashCells. I was hoping this was done by ag-grid itself